# Defining shell variables in a jenkins shell script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I see the below error when I try to create a shell variable in my JenkinsFile. How can I get around this issue?

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: file_name for
>   class: Script1

```
  sh"""
    file_name=`echo ${env.JOB_NAME} | sed -e 's/\\//-/g'`
    echo "file name =" $file_name
  """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/jenkins/comments/8u0w20/how_to_declare_variable_inside_a_shell_block_in/) helped me get the issue fixed. I had to do the below -

```
 sh"""
    file_name=`echo ${env.JOB_NAME} | sed -e 's/\\//-/g'`
    echo "file name =" \$file_name
  """
```